# Get directory size with threshold

Tags: c#, .net, directory, filesize

I have this following method to get directory size in bytes:

```
    public static long GetDirectorySize(string folderPath)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
        return di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(fi => fi.Length);
    }
```

I would like to add the following functionality - if the size of the directory is larger than 500 MB (or any input number), I would like it to return -1;

I can easily achieve it by changing the return to:

```
var size = di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(fi => fi.Length)
return (size <= 500*1024) ? size : -1;
```

This is not elegant nor efficient as it goes over all the files in the `.Sum(fi => fi.Length)`.

Is there an elegant way to add functionally which allows the caller to add a threshold ?

Note: I am trying to avoid iterating over all the files, if there is a folder with 100,000 files and the first is larger than 500 MB, no point in continuing iteration.

Comment: You could use `TakeWhile()` with side-effects.

Comment: Does this mean you want to the size on disk value as opposed to just the size of the directory? Or are the two negligible in what you need?

Comment: @keyboardP, I would like the size of directory on disk.
But if its over some threshold, I had like to return -1.
I don't want to iterate stop iteration once got to this threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can misuse LINQ to do this with side-effects:

```
int totalSize = 0;
directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     .TakeWhile(fi => (totalSize += fi.Length) < threshold)
     .Count();      // Force query to execute

return (totalSize <= threshold) ? totalSize : -1;
```

Comment: Looking good, can you please explain what do you mean by side effects?

Comment: @Ofiris: This lambda expression affects things outside of itself, so that calling it extra times will break your code.  LINQ callbacks are supposed to be pure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and answer, I had a problem with the solution abit, `totalSize` was not updated... I had to `.Sum` the enumeration result.. good to know `TakeWhile`

Comment: @Ofiris: Yes; I forgot about deferred execution.  You should simply add `.Count()` to the query.  (see edit)

Comment: @Ofiris: Yes.  More importantly, it enumerates through the entire sequence, forcing the query (with its side-effects) to run.

Answer (score 0):

In your method you can specify an optional argument set to 0 so if you input some value it will be set to that value, else will be 500mb. The method converts bytes to mb, and returns -1 if value is above and 1 if less:

EDIT:

```
public static int GetDirectorySize(string folderPath,int userinput = 0)
{
    double threshold = userinput == 0 ? 500 : userinput;
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
    double temp = (di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).TakeWhile(fl => (fl.Length / 1024f) / 1024f <= threshold).Sum(fi => fi.Length) / 1024f) / 1024f;
    temp = Math.Round(temp, 2);
    if (temp >= threshold)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
    // or  return temp > threshold ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Think of a case I have a folder with 100,000 files, the first is 501 MB, I had like to avoid iterating over the 100,000 files.